# Is there any possibility to OTP validation for changing user password (by API call) on keycloak?

Tags: c#, json, keycloak

I am trying to implement my own form for changing a user's password. I have found an API PUT call for changing user's password in Keycloak (12.0.4) but I have to precede this process with a OTP validation process or reauthenticate user somehow.
Is there any possibility to do this without writing keycloak's extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `prompt=login` parameter when redirecting requests to Keycloak so that it would ask the user to login (even if he/she has already logged in).  For example:

*yourkeycloak.com/auth/realms/your-realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=your-client-id&**redirect_uri=https://mywebsite.com/changepassword_url**&scope=openid&**prompt=login***

If user has 2FA enabled, the 2FA should also be done successfully. So I guess it would cover your requirements properly.